# How to Update duplicated Rows into One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, rows

I need to merge same entries and sum quantity row by quantity row. For example:

```
glass type  height   width    quantity
---------------------------------------
4DC          1500     600        1
4DC          1500     600        2
4DC          1200     500        5
4DC          1200     500        2
3DC          1500     600        2
```

will be:

```
glass type   height   width   quantity
---------------------------------------
4DC           1500     600      3
4DC           1200     500      7
3DC           1500     600      2
```

But I don't want any select query, I need to update table and delete duplicate rows and update one of them with sum quantity.

How can I do it?

Comment: You're going to need at *least* `SELECT` here, either to move the data to a temporary object or within a CTE. Also, you can't `DELETE` *and* `UPDATE` in a single query. You *could* use a `MERGE`, but I would suggest separate statements would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to replace the table:

```
select glasstype, height, width, sum(quantity) as quantity
into temp_t
from t
group by glasstype, height, width;

truncate table t;  -- backup first!

insert into temp_t (glasstype, height, width, quantity)
    select glasstype, height, width, quantity
    from temp_t;

drop table temp_t;
```

Alternatively, you could do this in two steps:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, sum(quantity) over (partition by glasstype, height, width) as new_quantity
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set quantity = new_quantity;

with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by glasstype, height, width order by glasstype) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this strategy and worked well. But I have a question. Should I delete this temporary table after every merge process?

Comment: You should probably create a variable like declare @tempTable table (glasstype varchar(10) ..... and therefore it is disposed whenever the query is done

Comment: @TuğhanAvcı . . . This does not use a temporary table, so you should delete it manually.I would nor recommend a table variable -- if the database crashes after you truncate the table, then you don't want to lose the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a similar thing to Gordon, however, I'd rename the objects instead:

```
SELECT GlassType,
       Height,
       Width,
       SUM(Quantity)
INTO dbo.NewTable
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY GlassType,
         Height,
         Width;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable',N'OldTable';
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.NewTable',N'YourTable';
GO
```

This means you still have a copy of your old table, which you won't be able to `TRUNCATE` if you have any foreign keys on. YOu will, however, have to recreate any existing constraints and indexes on the new `YourTable`

I would then create a Unique Constraint on your table, so that you can't end up with duplicates in the future.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT UC_TypeHeightWidth UNIQUE (GlassType,Height,Width);
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't change table names because it's full with data's

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that @TuğhanAvcı , when Gordon recommends the `TRUNCATE`; which **deletes** all your data, but still.